# where does the journal log exists on AEM Cloud service

Tags: osgi, aem, sling

I am trying to understand how [sling-distribution-journal](https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-distribution-journal/blob/master/docs/documentation.md) works.
As per the documentation, it says that persisted log is created.

On real AEM Cloud service production environment, what is framework used for append-only log implementation? Is it Apache Kafka or Apache sling-distribution-journal provided framework?
As per the diagram provided, it says this log file is written outside of AEM instance. I think this [LinkedList](https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-distribution-journal/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/distribution/journal/shared/DefaultDistributionLog.java#L41) stores all the log info but my doubt is what happens after, how this info is persisted in a file. I could not find the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

AEM Cloud uses Apache Kafka as the distribution backend.
Some insights can be found in https://adapt.to/2019/schedule/sling-content-distribution-for-the-cloud

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. I saw this before but what did not find how log info stored inside LinkedList is pushed to Kafka topic.